# ODataController and binary data

Tags: asp.net, odata

What is the best way to support accepting of binary data on an ODataController (in .net)? The binary stream can be large, atleast 2MB. I have a controller derived from ODataController (System.Web.Http.Odata.OdataController).

- How can I make this controller accept a Content-Type other than application/json (application/octet-stream perhaps)
- I am using a base64 encoded string of the binary data in the upload. Is there a better approach?

What I have currently inside the ODataController is:

> [HttpPut]
>   public float Put(string userId, string userType, [FromBody] string base64data)

Two pain points:

- base64data parses as null, unless the string is wrapped in an object. For example, a body like "This is a string" results in a null. The body, "{"value":"This is a string"}" parses fine.
- If I send more than 2MB of data, I again receive a null (with no errors).

What is the way to support binary data on an odata endpoint with higher allowed limits and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make this controller accept a Content-Type other than
>   application/json (application/octet-stream perhaps)

Use a custom media type formatter [Checkout an example here...](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2012/04/aspnet-web-api-series-part-5.html)

> I am using a base64 encoded string of the binary data in the upload.
>   Is there a better approach?

If you don't want to go through the custom media formatter route then you're better off posting your binary data as `multipart/form-data`. [Sample here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2)

> base64data parses as null, unless the string is wrapped in an object.
>   For example, a body like "This is a string" results in a null. The
>   body, "{"value":"This is a string"}" parses fine.

This is because the default json media formatter expects a json string. However your custom media type formatter will take of raw string.

> If I send more than 2MB of data, I again receive a null (with no
>   errors).

Because you're exceeding the max limit. You can change that using:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1000" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Learn more here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403